# Download an array as a CSV, but the data inside the array has commas in it

Tags: javascript, csv

I have an array of arrays, which looks something like this:

```
rows = [
        [Name, Description, Number ...],
        ["A thing", "Description, but it has commas in it", 6, ...],
        ...
       ]
```

I am trying to download this as a csv file. Here's the code I have so far:

```
// Make a csv from rows
let csv = rows.map(row => row.join(",")).join("\n");

document.getElementById("csv_download").setAttribute("download", "file_name.csv");

document.getElementById("csv_download").href = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(csv);
```

This works fine when there are no commas inside the array, but right now it sees the comma after "Description" and splits it there. I also can't split it by ", because some of the items are numbers.

How do I go about solving this?

Comment: Show us an example of the generated CSV - it is perfectly acceptable to have commas (or even newlines) inside ___quoted___ text in a CSV. Perhaps your parser doesn't understand that? Although it looks like your attempt to generate a CSV is a little naive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I go about solving this?

It varies. [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) is not a fully standardized format. But it will involve escaping those commas in the data in some way.

The most common way is to surround the fields that have commas with double quotes. If the data *also* has double quotes in it, you "escape" them with another double quote.

Applying that to your code:

```
let csv = rows.map(
    row => row.map(
        col => typeof col !== "string" ? col : `"${col.replace(/"/g, '""')}"`
    ).join(",")
).join("\n");
```

```js
const rows = [
    ["Name", "Description", "Number"],
    ["A thing", "Description, but it has \"commas\" in it", 6],
];
let csv = rows.map(
    row => row.map(
        col => typeof col !== "string" ? col : `"${col.replace(/"/g, '""')}"`
    ).join(",")
).join("\n");
console.log(csv);
```

But again, that's just one way to handle it.

Comment: *(Oops, I was erroneously surrounding the number with quotes. Hit refresh if you don't see the `typeof col !== "string"` at the **beginning** of the inner arrow function.)*